# Call a public method in Controller from the View in asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in the controller which returns a string.

I need to call this method from my view to get the string and show in the view.

I am using MVC2. how can i call a public method in controller from the View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really shouldn't be calling a method in the controller from the view, that's backwards from the MVC pattern. Controllers call views. You could either pass in the data to the view from the controller as it's called, or this might be a method that belongs in a helper class the view can use.

Edit: [Good starter tutorial](http://www.asp.net/(S(ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg))/learn/mvc/tutorial-09-cs.aspx) on helpers if you aren't familiar.

Comment: Upvoted. Controllers collect data and pass them on to the view. Views don't call controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Parrots is right, you shouldn't be accessing a controller from a view (use helpers as he says), but if you must:

```
<%= ((MyController)this.ViewContext.Controller).SomeMethod() %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inject some text into your page, you can call an action on the controller.  You can use Html.RenderAction(<actionname>, <controllername>).  This will drop the string in your View.

This is a simple way to populate parts of a view from different controllers.

Alternatively, is there a reason you can't call the method from the action that is generating the view, and put it in the ViewData/ViewBag?  You can then access it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call something (which view shouldn't do but...) you can provide view with a callback instead of referencing controllers in the view:

```
ViewData["callback"] = new Func<string>(() => "string");
// or for strongly typed views
Model.Callback = new Func<string>(() => "string");
```

in view

```
<%= ((Func<string>)ViewData["callback"])() %>
<%= Model.Callback() %>
```

But you *really* better not do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's necessary to call controller's method from view, for example, look into DevExpress gridview state management mechanism [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_ClientLayouttopic). For that

```
(ViewContext.Controller as MyController).SomeMethod();
```

is a pretty good solution.